# Should I use Chi-squared or exact binomial test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution, proportion

I am testing for the difference in 30-day mortality between an exposure group and a non-exposure group. The contingency table:

| Taking drug A | Dead at 30 days post-op | Alive at 30 days post-op |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | 3 | 25 |
| No | 9 | 218 |

Having read other answers on this site I'm not clear whether a Chi-squared or Exact binomial test is appropriate to test the null hypothesis that there is no association between taking drug A and 30 day mortality. Some sources seem to say the small group numbers mean the Exact binomial is more appropriate but I'm not clear.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do the tests give you the same (opposite) results?

Comment: Both tests are non-significant at 0.05 level. Chi-square, p = 0.11. Exact binomial test, p = 0.10.

Comment: So it does not matter whether you use one of them. However, exact test might be preferable as it does not receive "critics" for small cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried several standard tests: A test of two binomial proportions,
an equivalent chi-squared test in R with a simulated
P-value (on account of the small sample taking the drug), and Fisher's exact test. No P-values below 5%. The drug gives a
higher survival rate, but not enough larger to be statistically
significant at the 5% level.

Looking toward the future: If a similarly higher survival
rate persists when more subjects taking the drug can be included, the P-value
might be small enough for a significant difference. For example, with 9 survivors in 84, the P-value would be about 0.024. (Whether the
trial should be continued might depend on whether the drug
has risks or undesirable side effects.)

Here are results from a recent release of Minitab:

```
    Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample  X    N  Sample p
1       3   28  0.107143
2       9  227  0.039648

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  0.0674953
95% CI for difference:  (-0.0498455, 0.184836)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  Z = 1.13  P-Value = 0.260

* NOTE * The normal approximation may be inaccurate for small samples.

Fisher’s exact test: P-Value = 0.133
```

The smaller sample is too small for an accurate normal approximation.
Fisher's exact test is based on a hypergeometric distribution and so
can give an accurate P-value for small samples. However, Fisher's test
shows no significant difference.

Fisher's Exact Test in R, for verification: Same P-value as in Minitab

```
MAT = rbind(c(3,25),c(9,218))
MAT
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3   25
[2,]    9  218
fisher.test(MAT)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  MAT
p-value = 0.1326
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.4726708 12.6193587
sample estimates:
 odds ratio 
   2.889384
```

Chi-squared test in R using simulation to get an accurate P-value.
This test gives the same P-value as Minitab's test of two
proportions (when sample sizes are large enough to avoid
the error message).

```
chisq.test(MAT, cor=F, sim=T, B = 10000)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value 
        (based on 10000 replicates)

data:  MAT
X-squared = 2.5321, df = NA, p-value = 0.1325
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is clear there is no statistically significant difference in these samples. I take it from your answer that these tests (Binomial, Chi-squared, Fisher's etc.) are statistically valid to use in this scenario however.

Comment: Various tests comparing two binomial proportions are very similar to chi-sq test on a $2\times 2$ table, Some versions use continuity corrections for small sample sizes, but that usually makes little difference in P-value. Fisher's exact test traditionally used when counts are too small for good normal or chi-squared approximations, but modern software makes it feasible to use Fisher for larger counts. I think all are valid. Different authors have various favorites.